# Access JSON data array element

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following JSON data:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "count": 1194,
            "time_bin": "2014-10-06"
        },
        {
            "count": 1237,
            "time_bin": "2014-10-07"
        },
        {
            "count": 1144,
            "time_bin": "2014-10-08"
        },
        {
            "count": 1072,
            "time_bin": "2014-10-09"
        },
        {
            "count": 1082,
            "time_bin": "2014-10-10"
        },
        {
            "count": 406,
            "time_bin": "2014-10-11"
        },
        {
            "count": 465,
            "time_bin": "2014-10-12"
        }
    ],
    "error_flag": 0,
    "message": "7 rows returned"
}
```

I want to access "count" separately. How can I do that?

Comment: and what have you tried??

Comment: you need to iterate over `json_data.data` and access each items `count`

Comment: How about using a `for` loop?

Comment: `JSON.parse` and `for`.

Answer (score -1):

maybe something like this?

```
 var jsonData = { 
               data : [  {count:1194, time_bin:"2014-10-06"},
                            ...
                      ] , 
              error_flag:0, 
              message:"Here is your message"
         };
    var count;
    for (var i=0; i<jsonData.data.length; i++){
      count = jsonData.data[i].count;
      // do something
    }
```